# How to get permissions to "edit your text messages (SMS or MMS)"?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

I'm a beginner in android development and I'm working on a messaging app.
One feature that I really want is the ability to delete/modify existing messages. I've seen some apps on the play store with the permission to "edit your text messages (SMS or MMS)" but I am unable to find any example stating how to get that permission.
I've tried all the options from the "SMS" section of this page:https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#normal-dangerous

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you give us an example of such application, a link maybe? There is no such thing available in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission_group.html#SMS) nor I know something about it.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.promessage.message

Comment: Only the app the user sets as the default SMS app has the right to edit the text message db.   You cannot set yourself programatically.

Comment: That's a good point, got my upvote however, It's more like **a mistake** from Google play Because, messages are storing inside a file which **needs root permission at least** to have access and editing it. So, this cannot be true. But maybe with setting it as the default messaging app like gabe said. However, didn't see editing messages permission.

Comment: @Moshen no it doesn't require root.  it requires being the default SMS app.

Comment: @GabeSechan Try to install this app ( link above ). You can delete the messages even though the app is not the default messaging app.

Comment: Are you sure? I've never used it but, editing messages **permission** seems odd however.

Comment: @CodeWizard  Yeah- there is 0 chance I'm downloading any app.  I can tell you that as of 4.4 it was supposed ot be impossible, but bugs in the implementation allowed it until around 6.0.  It is not possible on a modern version of Android unless you have root or are the default SMS app.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4#SMS

Comment: Got the solution at: https://androidforums.com/threads/how-delete-sms.3701/      Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Add these to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
```

Comment: I could guess the same. But, the editing part is coming from one of these so there is actually no **separated** (from these) editing permission for messages